# SQL query using regex with string containing dashes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I'm trying to compare the title, that comes from *URL string* containing dashes, e.g.:

`Learning-Programming-Together-With-StackOverflow`

with my *DB record* that has either:

`Learning Programming Together With StackOverflow`

or

`Learning-Programming Together With StackOverflow`

Now, I'm not sure *how/which* `regex` to use with SQL query, to match my *DB records* above. 
So, when I supply an *URL string* with dashes, what would SQL regex query would look like to match 
my *DB records*?

I was thinking to try the following SQL query:

```
$sql = $this->db->conn->prepare("
    SELECT
      title
    FROM
      video
    WHERE
      title REGEXP :title 
    LIMIT 1
    ");
$sql->execute( array(
    ':title' => $title,
) );
```

but I am not sure at all how to combine it with `regex` `/([-])/g` that matches dashes?

Any help/advise please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```
$sql = $this->db->conn->prepare("
    SELECT
      title
    FROM
      video
    WHERE
      REPLACE(title, ' ', '-') = REPLACE(:title, ' ', '-')
    LIMIT 1
    ");
$sql->execute( array(
    ':title' => $title,
    ) );
```

Or `$title` can have the replacement done in php.

Comment: thank you, :) but some times, title might contain a dash/dashes, like in example above - `Learning-Programming Together With StackOverflow`. Your example will not catch that, right?

Comment: Yes it does. `Learning-Programming Together With StackOverflow` becomes `Learning-Programming-Together-With-StackOverflow`. Also its way faster than regex.

Comment: so you believe that it will match both db records: `Learning Programming Together With StackOverflow` and `Learning-Programming Together With StackOverflow` or even `Learning Programming Together With-StackOverflow`?

Comment: Yes, please try it out. It will replace all spaces with dashes in both  table field and `:title` and then compare them.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right, thank you very much, my friend! It works as you exampled it!

Comment: Do you have and idea why I simply can't use `REPLACE(title, " . $var1 . ", " . $var2 . ") = REPLACE(:title, " . $var1 . ", " . $var2 . ")` as it always return an error? If I do `REPLACE(" . $title . ", ' ', '-' ) = REPLACE(:title, ' ', '-')` it works just fine?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the single quotes. `REPLACE(title, '" . $var1 . "', '" . $var2 . "')`

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `preg_replace` before supplying string to MySQL query:

```
':title' => preg_replace('/[ -]+/', '', $title),
```

And use this in your query:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(title, ' ', ''), '-', '')
```

Basically idea is to remove all hyphens and spaces from both sides before comparing.

Comment: Thank you, but I would have to use `foreach` loop because sometimes it might contain dashes?